# Xfinity Wifi not listed on available networks

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have two laptops each with a 2.4 ghz frequency (only) internal wireless adapter as well as an old (2007) USB 2.4 wireless adapter that I can use but is large and clunky.

The newest internal adapter (realtek RTL8188CE Wireless LAN 802.11n PCI-NIC) will not display my home network in the list of available networks nor connect to it manually.  The other two adapters will display and connect to this network with no problem.  The home WiFi is an Xfinity Gateway and is the latest modem/router from Xfinity (Arris TGA4482A).

The one internal adapter that will not display my home WiFi network will connect to any other places I've tried using it.  I cannot see the network at a friend's home network that also uses the Xfinity (Arris TGA4482A) modem/router.

I have talked at length with Xfinity and they even sent a technician out to look at the problem.  He had never seen this happen before and after an hour could not figure it out.

I have changed out the realtek RTL8188CE Wireless LAN 802.11n PCI-NIC adapter with another (newer) one that supports b/g/n radio types; it does the same thing.  I have updated the drivers on the RTL8188CE and run the Windows network troubleshooting app and also have tried numerous adapter settings changes.

The adapter is not locked out nor blocked on my Xfinity home network.

I've tried splitting the Xfinity WiFi network into separate 2.4 and 2.5 ghz networks which did not help.

One last comment, the Ethernet adapter does work, but when using it I’m tethered to the modem and can’t use the laptop in different areas of my house.

Needless to say, I am completely bumfuzzled.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that Comcast knows about and intentionally caused a few years back. The update has been rolling out for a while now, but I've heard of this issue from as far back as 2019. I've actually had this problem too!

This is not a problem with your wifi cards or any devices. This is a problem with a setting on their router/modem combo boxes that no one knows or has the ability to change.

I recommend you buy your own router and modem, as you'll get full control over your devices instead of relying on the ISP to set up your wifi correctly... They aren't good at it.
I have Comcast as well, and use an old Arris SB8200 modem with a Netgear R9000 modem that has the latest DDWRT custom firmware on it. Looking at the amazon pages seems expensive until you remember that you're paying up to $20 a month EXTRA to rent their nonfunctional box.